# Firefox stops calling AJAX functions

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I have a database with points (1300 points), I plot them on a map. For most of these points, I want to plot an image in a popup, if the image exists.
So with AJAX I check if the path exists, if it does I plot the image, if not I do nothing.

Here is the code :

```
function doesFileExist(urlToFile) {
  var value;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', urlToFile,false); //requete synchrone : nécessaire pour l'affichage d'image mais long
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
      if (this.status == "404") {
          value = false;
      } else {
          value = true;
      }
    };
    }
    xhr.send();
    return value;
}
```

The main problem is that Firefox is plotting only few points most of the time. No problem with IE and Chrome.

I was wondering if I ask for too much ressources but it does not even struggle to plot the points in that case. It just plots the first ones and it stops loading. (so it is either long and complete, either fast and uncomplete).

**Does someone know how to avoid to plot only part of the points ?**

A solution could be to use a more efficient way than my AJAX function, if someone knows one, because it takes time to load because of this path checking (about 17 seconds with Chrome, 15s with Internet Explorer, 60s with Firefox).

[Here is website,](http://tbmigrateurs.eptb-vienne.fr/) you will be able to see by yourself.

My javascript call to the function (the div 'fiche' corresponds to the popup)

```
var fiche ="<div class='fiche'>";
    ouvrage = L.marker([latitude,longitude],{icon: unvisibleSmallIcon});
    var directory = "./photos/"+identite['Cours d\'eau'];
    var chemin_photo = directory+"/"+ identite['Identification'] +".JPG";
      if (doesFileExist(chemin_photo)){
        fiche += "<img class='img_logo' src='"+chemin_photo+"' alt='' width='80%' heigth='auto'> <br>";}

    ouvrage.bindPopup(fiche);
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to comment, I changed my code to :

```
<img class='img_logo' onerror='this.remove()' src='"+chemin_photo+"' alt='' width='80%' heigth='auto'> <br>"
```

However the remove function is not understood by Internet Explorer.

Then I tried to replace by another image, but image.onerror = "" does not work with Chrome.

```
<img class='img_logo' onerror='imgError(this)' src='"+chemin_photo+"' alt='' width='80%' heigth='auto'> <br>"
function imgError(image) {
    image.onerror = "";
    image.src = "./photos/no-image.png";
    return true;
  }
```

But Chrome says that "imgError is not defined at HTMLImageElement.onerror "

Comment: I don't know so much but... I think Firefox stop loading because Firefox is caching a lot of Request (see network in Firefox developer), it's possible?

Comment: Why don't you set a flag like hasPhoto and skip checking via ajax? Furthermore you could only trigger the request on hover to minimize the number of requests.

Comment: I didn't think of triggering only on hover ! But I think that removing image when error occurs as @charlietfl solution is simpler. What do you mean by "set a flag" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async false` is a terrible practice as it completely blocks everything in page

Why not just use an error handler on images and remove when error occurs

```
<img src="..." onerror="this.remove()">
```

Comment: Alternatively have a default "no image" url and change to that in error handler

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know how to do without async false :/ However the function remove does not works with IE ..

Comment: I would prefer to plot nothing when no image exists, as it will happen most of the time

Comment: Then create image element  yourself (`document.createElement('img')`) and use `onload` callback to add that image to the page

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. if I use document.createElement('img') it won't be a popup, right ?

Comment: I tried with an alternated image, but image.onerror = "" does not work for chrome

Comment: You need an identifier for each `fiche` element so you can append the new image element when it is successful